# How do I get information from wikipedia into my application

Tags: php, zend-framework, wikipedia

Hi guys I wish to get information for entries I have in my database from wikipedia like for example some stadiums and country information. I'm using Zend Framework and also how would I be able to handle queries that return multiple ambiguous entries or the like.. I would like all the help I can get here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a simple [HTTP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database) to the article you are looking to import. [Here's a good library](http://www.onderstekop.nl/articles/114/) which might help with parsing the HTML, though there are dozens of solutions for that as well, [including using the standard DOM model which is provided by php](https://www.php.net/dom).

```
<?php
require_once "HTTP/Request.php";

$req =& new HTTP_Request("http://www.yahoo.com/");
if (!PEAR::isError($req->sendRequest())) {
    echo $req->getResponseBody();
}
?>
```

Note, you will be locked out of the site if your traffic levels are deemed too high. (If you want a HUGE number of articles, [download the database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database))

Comment: Whoa I didn't know that you could do that - I've downloaded the database and started a new thread on the meticulous task of importing it - thanks for the tip man :)

Answer (score 11):

Wikipedia is based on MediaWiki, offering an Application Programmable Interface (API).

You can check out MediaWiki API on Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Documentation for MediaWiki API - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API

Comment: Thats cool but are there any tutorials or starter code to get started. Basically I don't have the exact name of the article just an entry in my database and I was wondering if I could get a corresponding article from the wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://codeinclude.blogspot.com/2010/12/php-bot-to-get-wikipedia-definitions.html) blog has a really good code for get a definition from wiki

```
<?php
//FUNCTION THAT :PARAMETER - KEYWORD , AND RETURNS WIKI DEFINITION (IN ARRAY FORMAT)
function wikidefinition($s) {
//ENGLISH WIKI
    $url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=".urlencode($s)."&format=xml&limit=1";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; he; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8");

    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($page);
    if((string)$xml->Section->Item->Description) {
        return array((string)$xml->Section->Item->Text, 
                     (string)$xml->Section->Item->Description, 
                     (string)$xml->Section->Item->Url);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
//END OF FUNCTION WIKIDEFINITIONS


//USE OF FUNCTION
$data = wikidefinition('Bangladesh') ;
//var_dump( wikidefinition('bangladesh') ) ; //displays the array content
echo "Word:"       . $data[0] . "<br/>";
echo "Definition:" . $data[1]  . "<br/>";
echo "Link:"       . $data[2] . "<br/>";

?>
```